# Verify email with codeigniter sending a codeigniter function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I did same as described in **Verify email with codeigniter**  and all work seems ok from my side, but it only works when I give all the direction like: `http://localhost/site_name/controller/function_name/parameter` the parameter is my random code, but when I learn codeigniter it says that the links to a function we put in like this:

```
 echo site_url('controller/function_name/parameter')
```

When I do this, the link doesn't work.

Comment: Load [url helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) before use of that function. Best in `APPPATH.'config/autoload.php'` file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to load the url helper in your code.

Either add it system wide in the file:

application/config/autoload.php

```
 $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

or you can define it in your controller:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

But just in case please ensure that you have the base_url parameter set up in your appliation/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site_name/';
```

Comment: i load this, and email helper too

Comment: can you paste in the html code of the generated link?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Can you copy and paste in the view or controller code where you have this issue with site_url() function?

Comment: i can do it in the view, in the controller i never have the need to do this